# How to learn creating a datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I just would like to ask for some suggestions on how or where I could learn on how to create a datepicker in html without using bootstrap or any built/finished javascript and css. I would like to learn from scratch on how some developers created these.

The one that when you clicked on the textbox, the datepicker would appear under the textbox and then when I clicked on a specific date, it would generate automatically on the textbox with a default format. I would like to practice creating one for a birthday field.

Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: What do you mean sir?

Comment: Why do you urge to create a datepicker where there are plenty of them available for free. If you need to customize it then there are tutorials as well. If you really really need to learn how it works then hope this would [help you](https://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Web-Style-Sheets/Creating-a-Simple-Date-Picker-with-JavaScript-and-CSS/).

Comment: Because I would want to learn how the datepicker is created and how it works. Although there are free datepickers that are ready for download, I would just want to learn the most basic or simple datepicker. I already tried that tutorial but I am referring to the textbox that when clicked, the datepicker will appear. Thanks by the way. :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To create your own Datepicker first you need to understand the
[Javascript Date Functions](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp)
This functions is what you'll be using for most of the time in date handling.

See this sample code I made, it's not near perfect but it get the jobs done if I'd say

My Date Picker
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FED216E6BIIJ

Comment: coming from 3 years later, I don't have an idea on my codes here. its messy but it works.

Answer (score -3):

here `<input type="date" name="date">`

Comment: The problem is that it cannot be used in IE 11 and firefox. I would just like to have a datepicker with UI.

Comment: this has nothing to do with creating your _own_ datepicker. This is a built in browser datepicker.